# The continuity of a curve created through a geometric progression

Tags: continuity, fractals

Can I create a continuous curve using numerical discrete data? In this case, I'm looking at the area of Sierpinski triangles which decrease at a rate of $\frac{3}{4}$ per reiteration of the fractal. Since the area is represented in a geometric progression wouldn't an exponential curve fit the infinite data set as the number of re-iterations goes to infinity?

However, I've heard people say that since the number of re-iterations is an integer value, then the curve cannot be continuous.

How can I understand where a continuous curve applies to integer values in a geometric progression?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that the data is *discrete*, rather than continuous. It can be *modeled* with a continuous function, however. In particular, the function

$$A(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x$$

fits the data quite well at the integers. Here's an image ([generated on Observable](https://observablehq.com/d/bee008ff6cfbb94e)) illustrating the fit:

[image]